# SBT asking for a command

Tags: linux, scala, installation, sbt

So I am trying to run sbt on my linux VM. I downloaded sbt, and I added a plugin from my current cs class.

I created a directory with a src/main/scala folder in it.

I also wrote a script and saved it on the scala file.

However, every time I try to run sbt on my terminal, I get two lines:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/student/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] set current project to student (in build file:/home/student/)
>
```

It asks for a command when it should not. I have tried 'test', 'run', and nothing works. And I am inside the directory which has the structure necessary.

My goal is to get to sbt console so I can scala.

Comment: what does it mean "nothing works", what do you mean by not working? Unless your project directory is /home/student you are in wrong directory.

Comment: [info] set current project to student (in build file:/home/student/Lecture1) That's where the project is, but I get the same message and prompt when I change the directory and run sbt.

Comment: ..and by not working, I mean I can't run scala inside sbt because it keeps asking for a command

Comment: the command to "run scala" is `console`

Answer (score 2):

In order to execute a Scala script, that is, using Scala as scripting language, you don't need SBT (assuming you also have installed scala). You can invoke your script directly as follows:

`shell> scala myscript.scala` where `myscript.scala` may contain:

```
println("hello world!")
```

The SBT use case and the above project structure is needed when you have a Scala application, that is, at least an object with a `main(args: Array[String])` method. e.g.

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world!")
    }
  }
```

You can find more details about how to get started on [Scala official site](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html)